# SQL Server Spatial: Get length of multiple Points

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, gis, sql-server-2012

I have a table containing many SQL Server Geography Coordinates (geography datatype). The points are correctly ordered in the table. I want to combine these points to a line and calculate the total length of the polyline.

My idea was the following:

1. UNION the Geography Coordinates. (*this creates a MULTI POINT.*)
2. Convert the `MULTI POINT` to a `LINE STRING`.
3. Use `.STLength()` to get the length

Is there an efficient way to union existing point without constructing a **LINESTRING** from a string?

I am using SQL Server 2012.